# How to acquire a file path with another program in Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, file, terminal, path

Let's say I want to save the path of a file to a variable in Linux terminal. I could do it like this:
`VARIABLE=/home/john/Documents/example.txt`

Is there a way to do this with another program like Ranger for example? In pseudo-code:

```
echo "Choose a file:"
// launch Ranger
// return a file path into a variable
echo $example_variable
// prints the file you chose with Ranger
```

Comment: Learn about command substitution in shell https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution
And look for a tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
echo "Choose a file:"
tempfile=$(mktemp)
ranger --choosefile="$tempfile"
read -r example_variable < "$tempfile"
rm -f "$tempfile"
```

I think it should be self explanatory.

Comment: If this works for you, you can consider marking this as the accepted answer. If you get a better answer in future you can (and are encouraged to) un-accept mine and accept the other answer.